# Strictly parsing dates with moment

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

When you create a `moment` from a date string and pass in the format, moment very loosely checks the date string against the format. for example the following dates are all valid

```
moment('1','YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() //true
moment('1988-03','YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() //true
moment('is a val1d date!?#!@#','YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() //true
```

Is there any way to only accept dates that match the specified format?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, including delimeters.

```
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();       // true
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // false
```

Found in [this section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) of the Moment JS docs